# How to upload an image into a SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to insert an image in SQL and then recall it on HTML. I'm currently trying to insert the image into the database, returning this error

> "Error sending the file. Please try again! Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect () in
>   /membri/tiservo/inserimentooprodotti/image/write_db.php:10 Stack
>   trace: # 0 {main} thrown in
>   /membri/tiservo/inserimentoprodotti/image/write_db.php online 10 "

Where have I gone wrong? to others it works

P.S I will not insert the code to call the image in HTML as I have not yet tried if it works.

HTML FORM:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Carica file nel DB</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="upload" action = "write_db.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" name="invia" value="Invia file">
            <input type = "file" name = "file_inviato" />
            <input type = "submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    // Verifico eventuali problemi nell'upload del file
    if ((!isset($_FILES["file_inviato"])) || ($_FILES["file_inviato"]["error"] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK))
        echo("Errore nell'invio del file. Riprova!");

    // Connessione e selezione del database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "MYUSER", "")
    or die("Connessione non riuscita: " . mysql_error());

    if (!mysql_select_db("MY_DB"))
        die("Selezione database fallita!");

    // Recupero delle informazioni sul file inviato
    $nome_file_temporaneo = $_FILES["file_inviato"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome_file_vero = $_FILES["file_inviato"]["name"];
    $tipo_file = $_FILES["file_inviato"]["type"];

    // Leggo il contenuto del file
    $dati_file = file_get_contents($nome_file_temporaneo);

    // Preparo il contenuto del file per la query sql
    $dati_file = addslashes($dati_file);

    // Query per inserire il file nel DB
    $query = "INSERT INTO tabella_file SET
              nome = '$nome_file_vero', 
              tipo = '$tipo_file', 
              dati = '$dati_file'";

    mysql_query($query)
    or die("Query non valida: " . mysql_error());

    // Messaggio di successo
    echo("Memorizzazione del file <b>$nome_file_vero</b> nel database eseguita correttamente!");
```

### Edit

Thanks for all the answers you have given me, I didn't know that it was no longer supported. I change the question so that someone can help me further.

Could you give me a working code simply to take the image insert it in the database and then recall it from HTML.

Comment: What version of php are you using? mysql_ functions were removed entirely in php7.

[link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

I'd look at mysqli_ functions or PDO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: INSERT has no SET clause. Seems like you've mixed the INSERT and UPDATE syntax.

Comment: Thanks for information use this PHP 7.3.11 - Optimized for AlterVista

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I discovered that it is no longer supported by having version 7.1.
I have updated the question, always take a look if you like

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 7.0 this function has been removed as an alternative use mysqli_connect().

Also stated in the Warning in PHP Documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm just using PHP and I didn't know this.

Comment: this PHP 7.3.11 - Optimized for AlterVista

Comment: You probably just need to use the other function and the rest will follow.

I would not recommend storing complete images in the database due to the file size. Better to store the path to the file in the database and store the binary in the file system.

But thats completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
$host="localhost";<br/>
$user="MYUSER";<br/>
$password="";<br/>
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);<br/>
mysqli_select_db($con,"MY_DB"); <br/>
session_start(); //To start the session<br/>
$query=mysqli_query($con,your query);<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I discovered that it is no longer supported by having version 7.1.
I have updated the question, always take a look if you like